# How to check if process is running on Red Hat Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, redhat

I've been using a modified class I found to check if another instance of the same process is already running, the problem is that the method of checking for the process adds another instance of the same process.

When my application starts, a new process ID is created and is visible with:

```
ps -A | grep "AppName"
```

With this I get a since entry returned, I then check for another instance of the application using:

```
QString strCMD = "ps -A | grep \"" + mcstrAppName + "\"";
QProcess objProc;
objProc.start("bash", QStringList() << "-c" << strCMD);

if ( objProc.waitForStarted() != true || objProc.waitForFinished() != true ) {
    mcpobjApp->exit(cleanExit(-1, "Unable to determine if another instance is running!"));
    return;
}
```

As soon as the 'start' method is called another instance of the same application appears in the process table, again, verified with:

```
ps -A | grep "AppName"
```

Two entries now appear each with a different PID.  I've also tried:

```
QString strOptions = "-A | grep \"" + mcstrAppName + "\"";
QProcess objProc;
objProc.start("ps", QStringList() << strOptions);
```

The result is the same, two entries in process table.

Is there a way to check the process table for another instance without adding an additional instance?

Comment: There no way of seeing if a specific executable is running, from inside the specific executable itself, not without actually loading and running the executable. Instead I suggest you use some kind of file lock on a specific file. If the file is locked then the program is running and you do whatever you need to be doing. If it's not locked then you lock it and continue. Or perhaps a shared semaphore or something similar.

Comment: The issue with that method is that if the file is locked and then there is some problem with the executable, a watchdog cannot restart the process either.

Comment: How about a PID file? A file whose contents is the PID of the running process? If it exists and the PID exists and matches the executable, then the process is running. If the file doesn't exist, or the PID doesn't exist, or it exists but isn't matching the executable then the program is not running and you overwrite the PID file. Works well with a watchdog doing the same check.

Comment: I was just thinking the same, I will try this now and report back.

Comment: I will also add the current system time to each entry in the file, so the application and watchdog can determine if the entry is live or not.

Comment: You could also just "touch" (rewrite) the file at regular intervals, and then check the files last-modification timestamp.

Comment: Smart thinking :)...or maybe not...if mutiple applications can touch the file then how do others know which one is live and which isn't updating...the idea of each entry in the PID file having its own timestamp is so each application can tell if the other is live.

Comment: If your code uses a resource that cannot be shared by multiple instances, such as listening on a socket, then you don't need to check the other instance. Let it fail and bailout when exclusive access to the resource fail. This will be your indication that another instance is already running. However, if the instance will run using the same resource and cause corruption, such as reading and writing to a file, then this is a good candidate to use a pid file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a pid file. It's the standard procedure for daemons on linux.

```
 int createPidFile(const char *pidFile, int flags)
{
    int fd;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    fd = open(pidFile, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd == -1)
        errExit("Could not open PID file %s", pidFile);
    if (flags & CPF_CLOEXEC) 
    {
        /* Set the close-on-exec file descriptor flag */
        flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD); /* Fetch flags */
        if (flags == -1)
            errExit("Could not get flags for PID file %s", pidFile);
        flags |= FD_CLOEXEC; /* Turn on FD_CLOEXEC */
        if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, flags) == -1) /* Update flags */
            errExit("Could not set flags for PID file %s", pidFile);
    }
    return fd;
}
```

Source **The Linux Programming Interface**

This creates a file and locks it so no other process can open it. It marks it as close on exit so the file will close when the process exits through normal or abnormal termination. If an instance of your program is already running, this function will fail and you can just exit.

**EDIT:**
The pid file should be in the temporary partition. the specific location varies depending on your distribution, just look on your system where other daemons create their pid files.

Comment: On Redhat, pid files are usually in `/var/run`.  `tmpwatch` can delete your pidfile if you put it in /tmp.

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution I used, which I wrote myself, prototype: clsSingleInstance.h:

```
class clsSingleInstance : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit clsSingleInstance(const QString& strAppName, QApplication* pobjApp);

public slots:
    void check();

private:
    const int mcintDelay = 3000;
    const QString mcstrAppName;

    qint64 mint64PID;
    QApplication const* mcpobjApp;
    QTimer* mptmrCheck;

    Q_DISABLE_COPY(clsSingleInstance);
};
```

Implementation, clsSingleInstance.cpp:

```
    #include "clsSingleInstance.h"
    /**
     * @brief clsSingleInstance::clsSingleInstance
     * @param strAppName : The application name as it will appear in the process list
     * @param pobjApp : Pointer to the applicaiton instance
     */
    clsSingleInstance::clsSingleInstance(const QString& strAppName
                                        ,QApplication* pobjApp)
                                        :QObject(pobjApp)
                                        ,mcstrAppName(strAppName)
                                        ,mcpobjApp(pobjApp) {
    //Save the process ID
        mint64PID = mcpobjApp->applicationPid();
    //Run check now to determine if another instance is running
        check();
    //Set-up timer to check for another instance regularly
        mptmrCheck = new QTimer(this);

        if ( mptmrCheck != NULL ) {
            connect(mptmrCheck, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(check()));
            mptmrCheck->start(mcintDelay);
        }
    }
    /**
     * @brief clsSingleInstance::check
     * Checks application instances running
     */
    void clsSingleInstance::check() {
        const QString cstrCheckFile = clsMainWin::mcszConfigPath
                                        + mcstrAppName + ".pid";
        QFile objPID(cstrCheckFile);

        if ( objPID.exists() == true ) {
    //Check the file date / time stamp
            QDateTime dtCreated = QFileInfo(cstrCheckFile).created()
                     ,dtNow = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
            qint64 int64Created = dtCreated.toMSecsSinceEpoch()
                  ,int64Now = dtNow.toMSecsSinceEpoch()
                  ,int64Diff = int64Now - int64Created;
    //Is the file current and being updated?
            if ( int64Diff < (mcintDelay * 2) ) {
    //PID file is live, read it
                if ( objPID.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) == true ) {
    //PID file exists, it should only contain a single ID
                    QByteArray arybytContent = objPID.readAll();
                    QString strContent = arybytContent.trimmed();
                    objPID.close();

                    if ( strContent.toLongLong() != mint64PID ) {
                        qInfo("Another instance already present...");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    //Create / update PID file
        if ( objPID.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly) == true ) {
            QString strPID = QString::number(mint64PID);
            objPID.write(strPID.toLatin1());
            objPID.close();
        }
    }
```